# Left outer join automatically add data to the parent table

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

A normal

```
Select * from Customer;
```

yields me 1060 records with `customer ID 1064` at last.

When I make a complex query

```
Select A,B,C,D 
from customer 

left outer join ...
left outer join....
left outer join....
group by ...
order by...
```

it yeilds me 1269 records. That is still fine with left outer join. But why is it adding the values to `customer ID` above 1060 (ie 1061-1269) which actually is not a data in **customer** table. Is there a rule ?

Comment: what's the datatype of the customer id? please post actual data and actual query: with partial and not real data/code is quite difficult to make anything but wild guesses.

Comment: It would be easier to discuss your issue if your would provide some sample data and be a little more specific about your query. Nevertheless if in a left joined table are multiple rows for one matching row of customer, then this row is returned in combination with each matching row of the left joined table.

Comment: Hi gyus, thank you ! It was my mistake . I didn't pay attention to the row limit in SQLYog. I am deleting this Question

Answer (score 0):

LEFT JOIN preserves unmatched rows from the joined tables. So you'll get additional rows from both tables where they don't share a value in the columns you're trying to join.

Try this:

```
create table #test1( id int, dat nvarchar(9))
insert into #test1 values (1, 'test1')

create table #test2( id int, dat nvarchar(9))
insert into #test1 values (2, 'test2')

select * from #test1 t1 left outer join #test2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

You'll get two rows back, even though the tables have no matching id values.

Contrast with this:

```
select * from #test1 t1 inner join #test2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

Which gets nothing, because there's no shared value in the id column that we're joining on.

Comment: Hi Matt, thank you ! It was my mistake . I didn't pay attention to the row limit in SQLYog. I am deleting this Question

Answer (score 0):

Query can fetch more records than customer table as other tables can contains multiple records against single cust id, but cust_id should not exceed than1064 as this is your last cust id in customer table...if this is heppening then show sample data with result set.

Comment: Hi Zafar , thank you ! It was my mistake . I didn't pay attention to the row limit in SQLYog. I am deleting this Question